# <dl> description lists side by side horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two description lists (one of coffee shops around a destination, the other of donut shops around that destination) that I want to show up side by side horizontally. I have tried all combinations of `display:inline-block` and `float` to no avail. No matter what, one list is always covered by the other.

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JamesGold/e1fsu5jt/

The lists are populated by the javascript code which calls the Google Places library.

edit: the lists don't seem to be populating in the fiddle, but they do get populated in my browser... does fiddle not support Google Places API calls?

Comment: helps a lot to check the console and see what error messages are displayed there... looking at your fiddle, your external script `coffee_and_donuts.js` is obviously missing as you're referring to it with a relative url...

Comment: in jsfiddle, your external files have to be added to 'External Resources' and you do not have to call files of which you're adding the code to the fiddle's js portion...

Comment: sorry, i'm new to this. how should i add coffee_and_donuts.js to external resources?

Comment: Is the problem that you don't get the css to work, or the javascript? Maybe you could use the result of the js as fiddle.

Comment: The CSS is the issue. The javascript works fine.

Comment: coffee_and_donuts.js is just sitting on my local machine

Comment: Here is how you can place stuff in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e1fsu5jt/3/ - watch the left hand side settings and the way i removed doctype and the head section and all...

Comment: by the way, as explained in my answer, apparently everything is not ok with your js code... again, have a look at the console for errors... if you need help with that, you may have to ask it in a new question, as this one is about css positioning...

Comment: Show *relevant* code in the question itself. Use a static HTML example unless using JavaScript is *essential* to the problem. If the problem is about *formatting* a `dl` element, it should be presented as a purely HTML and CSS problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them inside a `div` and floating should work just fine.

```
<div style="width: 50%; float:left;">
  <dl>
    <dt id="coffee1"></dt>
      <dd id="coffee1_address"></dd>
      <dd id="coffee1_number"></dd>
      <dd id="coffee1_rating"></dd><br>
    <dt id="coffee2"></dt>
      <dd id="coffee2_address"></dd>
      <dd id="coffee2_number"></dd>
      <dd id="coffee2_rating"></dd><br>
    <dt id="coffee3"></dt>
      <dd id="coffee3_address"></dd>
      <dd id="coffee3_number"></dd>
      <dd id="coffee3_rating"></dd><br>
    <dt id="coffee4"></dt>
      <dd id="coffee4_address"></dd>
      <dd id="coffee4_number"></dd>
      <dd id="coffee4_rating"></dd><br>
    <dt id="coffee5"></dt>
      <dd id="coffee5_address"></dd>
      <dd id="coffee5_number"></dd>
      <dd id="coffee5_rating"></dd>
  </dl>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 50%; float:right;">
  <dl>
    <dt id="donuts1"></dt>
      <dd id="donuts1_address"></dd>
      <dd id="donuts1_number"></dd>
      <dd id="donuts1_rating"></dd><br>
    <dt id="donuts2"></dt>
      <dd id="donuts2_address"></dd>
      <dd id="donuts2_number"></dd>
      <dd id="donuts2_rating"></dd><br>
    <dt id="donuts3"></dt>
      <dd id="donuts3_address"></dd>
      <dd id="donuts3_number"></dd>
      <dd id="donuts3_rating"></dd><br>
    <dt id="donuts4"></dt>
      <dd id="donuts4_address"></dd>
      <dd id="donuts4_number"></dd>
      <dd id="donuts4_rating"></dd><br>
    <dt id="donuts5"></dt>
      <dd id="donuts5_address"></dd>
      <dd id="donuts5_number"></dd>
      <dd id="donuts5_rating"></dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/e1fsu5jt/6/ - I added the text `donuts` to the right hand side column (see explanation below).

**Note**: you may not see donuts on the right hand side because, for some reason, no result is being returned, but that's a whole different question (nothing to do with css positioning).

**EDIT**: actually, you don't have to wrap them inside a `div`, it's just best practice. You could apply the same styles to the `dl` elements just as well, you just have to be sure to do it right. Not sure what you did before why `float` didn't work for you, but it should. You just have to make sure one of the elements has `left`, the other one `right` and both have `width` specified that add up to the total of their container or to 100% (including margins and paddings!).

Here is an updated fiddle without the extra `div`'s: http://jsfiddle.net/e1fsu5jt/9/

Comment: Can you explain why they had to be wrapped in a div?